# java: remove(component); does not remove button instantly

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

so I'm using this to remove the button from the JPanel. However, the button is not removed instantly, but disappears only after I minimize the window. Any suggestions?

```
   jBOption2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    jPanel.remove(jButton2);
```

Comment: You have to revalidate and repaint the component

Comment: component.repaint() did it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it should work the same way as mentioned in this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438512/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438512/fully-remove-jlabel-from-jpanel-not-setvisiblefalse)

```
jPanel.remove(jButton2);
jPanel.revalidate();
jPanel.repaint();
```

I hope it fits your question ;)